# gamecenter not getting result

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, game-center

```
 if(myScoreValue.value==300)//achievement for getting 300 points.
{
    GKAchievement *achievement= [[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Score4"];
    achievement.percentComplete = 100.0;
    achievement.showsCompletionBanner=YES;
    if(achievement!= NULL)
    {
        [achievement reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSError *error)
         {
             if(error != nil){
                 NSLog(@"Achievement failed");
             } else {
                 NSLog(@"Achievement Success");
             }
         }];
    }
}
```

When the user gets a score of exactly 300, they get an achievement, but it is not working if they go over 300. How do I fix it?

Comment: Please put a `.` at the end of every sentence.

Comment: More details might be helpful; when are you running this code? Perhaps it's running too frequently?

Comment: my game is based on a scoring system if you get 300 you get an achievement

Comment: i put the statement to make it if the score is equal to 300 they get the achievement but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

> When the user gets a score of exactly 300, they get an achievement, but it is not working if they go over 300. How do I fix it?

The problem is that you are checking if the score is exactly 300; if the score is (for example) 302, the code you show is not executed. You should check if the score is higher or equal to 300.

In [GameCenterManager.m](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKTapper/Listings/Classes_GameCenterManager_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010283-Classes_GameCenterManager_m-DontLinkElementID_8), an example available in the Apple's developer center, you can read the following comment (it is at the begin of `-submitAchievement:percentComplete:`):

> GameCenter check for duplicate achievements when the achievement is submitted, but if you only want to report new achievements to the user, then you need to check if it's been earned  before you submit.  Otherwise you'll end up with a race condition between `loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler` and `reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler`. To avoid this, we fetch the current achievement list once, then cache it and keep it updated with any new achievements.

This means that eventually you could report an achievement that has been already gained from the user; you need to be careful doing that if you are using `loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler` and `reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler`.
For your code, it means you could use `if (myScoreValue.value >= 300) { /*…*/ }`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion.

Read this official documentary of Apple as class reference http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKAchievement_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

```
   OR
```

Here is very useful source from GitHub- listed of TypeOneError http://www.typeoneerror.com/articles/post/game-center-achievement-notification